# How to use Redux-connected component with react router?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm trying to use connected to Redux storage component with react router (simplified):

```
export class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    // ... some methods goes here
    export default connect(
        state => ({
            someState: state.someState,
        }),
        dispatch => bindActionCreators({
            someAction,
        }, dispatch)
   )(SomeComponent);
}
```

Somewhere, where I need connected component with react router:

```
const routes = (
    <Route path='/' component={Layout}>
       <Route path='/somepath' component={SomeComponent} />
    </Route>
);

export default class Verification extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const createElement = (Component, props) => {
        return (
          <Component />
        );
       };
       return (
           <div>
               <Provider store={store}>
                   <Router history={browserHistory} createElement={createElement}>
                      {routes}
                   </Router>
              </Provider>
           </div>
       );
  }
}
```

It works fine with components without `connect()`, but unfortunately it fails for connected component as `Layout` component needs `Children`, but `Children` is undefined.

Is it possible to pass component to the router in inline style?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was just in using plain import `import A from './a';` instead of `import { A } from './a';` for Redux components.